# how to find xpath getText not working Selenium with java

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Html code is:

```
**p style="width: 46%;" xpath="1"
input ng-disabled="true" type="text" class="EOR-btn ng-pristine ng-valid" name="eor" id="eor" ng-model="vm.EOR" placeholder="" style="width: 96%;" disabled="disabled"
/p**  

** Invoice number : 350971854 **
```

how to find Xpath, copy invoice number. And paste in Excel.

find xpath try to

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//input[@id='eor']").getText();
```

input given me null? So I need to copy Invoice number.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Why are you not using the `name` or `id` locator instead of the xpath locator?

Comment: how to find Xpath, copy invoice number. And paste in Excel. -  there are 3 question, there should be 3 tickets.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//p[@id='eor']).getText();
```

Try this

Comment: One liners are not great answers. Please include some explanation as to why the answer given by you would help the OP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[@id='eor']"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)